# Does Go support Inheritence?

Tags: go

I have heard a lot of people talk about Go, and how it does not support inheritance. Until actually using the language, I just went along with the crowd and listened to the hear say. After a little messing about with the language, getting to grips with the basics. I came across this scenario:

```
    package main

type Thing struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type UglyPerson struct {
    Person
    WonkyTeeth bool
}

type Person struct {
    Thing
}

type Cat struct {
    Thing
}


func (this *Cat) SetAge(age int){
    this.Thing.SetAge(age)
}

func (this *Cat GetAge(){
     return this.Thing.GetAge() * 7
}

func (this *UglyPerson) GetWonkyTeeth() bool {
    return this.WonkyTeeth
}

func (this *UglyPerson) SetWonkyTeeth(wonkyTeeth bool) {
    this.WonkyTeeth = wonkyTeeth
}

func (this *Thing) GetAge() int {
    return this.Age
}

func (this *Thing) GetName() string {
    return this.Name
}

func (this *Thing) SetAge(age int) {
    this.Age = age
}

func (this *Thing) SetName(name string) {
    this.Name = name
}
```

now, what this does it composes the Person and Cat Structs, from the Thing Struct. By doing so, not only does the Person and Cat struct share the same Fields as the Thing Struct, but also, through composition, the methods of Thing are also shared. Is this not inheritance? Also by implenting an interface as such:

```
type thing interface {
    GetName() string
    SetName(name string)
    SetAge(age int)
}
```

All three Structs are now joined or should I say, can be used in a homogenous fashion, such as an array of "thing".

So, I lay it on you, is this not inheritance?

*Edit*

Added a new derived Struct called "Ugly person" and Overridden the SetAge method for Cat.

Comment: No, **as you said** it's **not inheritance** but **composition**. To be pedantic...what do you say? person IS a thing or person HAS a thing? You can't pass a thing instead of a person. About interfaces well yes, it's **somehow** inheritance but you can't inherit implemented behaviors, just their definition. Imagine to say that a person CAN DO something (but each implementer has to do it in its own way).

Comment: But the syntax sugar, makes it feel like inheritance, isn't this all there is really to inheritance when using an OO language?

Comment: I would say shares traits of a thing.

Comment: I don't know, I think that this form of composition is a little different to normal Object composition. It is clear when creating a system that an object is composed of many objects. But the syntax sugar in go would give the Cat and Person GetName().

Comment: But composition/inheritance are not syntax sugar, they're different behaviors!

Comment: If Go didn't use syntax sugar, I would be calling Person.Thing.SetAge(), not Person.SetAge(). This I think is the confusion. It looks like inheritance, acts like inheritance, but in fact is old school functional decomposition.

Comment: inheritance is sugar. If you get down to the nuts and bolts of programming, you find that most of the abstractions we depend upon in the OO world are nothing more than syntax sugar. Its why they break. Its why OO doesn't scale when using Threads. Its all smoke and mirrors.

Comment: Of course not! Of course everything can be written in pure assembly but this doesn't mean **abstractions** and **concepts** are syntax sugar (syntax sugar = a shortcut to write something more friendly/shortly, they don't/can't change behavior). You can program  OOP-style in C but it's still OOP, inheritance doesn't change **meaning** and **expected behavior** (doesn't matter how language exposes that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is inheritance but probably not the sort of inheritance you are probably after. Your example look promising b/c `Person` and `Cat` are behaviorally and structurally equal to each other modulo the type names.

As soon as you'd attempt to use this "inheritance" to 'extend' some base type with, for example added fields, you'll find that the receiver of the "base class" is always the base class, never the extended one. IOW, you cannot achieve structurally polymorphous type hierarchy.

OTOH, Go supports purely behavioral inheritance via interfaces. Embedding one interface into another *does* create an inheritance tree.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Thing struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (t *Thing) me() {
    fmt.Printf("I am a %T.\n", t)
}

type Person struct {
    Thing
}

func (p *Person) Iam() {
    fmt.Printf("I am a %T.\n", p)
}

type Cat struct {
    Thing
}

func (c *Cat) Iam() {
    fmt.Printf("I am a %T.\n", c)
}

func main() {
    var p Person
    var c Cat

    p.me()
    p.Iam()

    c.me()
    c.Iam()
}
```

Comment: could you give an example of what your saying please, using the daft code I have above? Just so that I understand fully. I don't know, add ShoeSize :)

Comment: +1 right but looking at original question I wouldn't beat that OP did understand what you mean...

Comment: I have extended Person by adding a new Struct called UglyPerson and giving him wonkyTeeth. I don't see a problem so far?

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: I'm not sure if I made a good example, but please have a look at http://play.golang.org/p/N3LIEt0xTR The point is that the "base" class doesn't see if it exists alone or is embedded in any child type. All what `Thing`'s method see is only the `Thing`. If the child type overrides Thing's method, within a Thing the non-overridden method would still be called instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's called composition. Methods of Person or Cat have no direct access to the fields of Thing. Also if e.g. Cat implements an own SetAge() and you want to call the one of Thing you would have to call myCat.Thing.SetAge(42) instead of myCat.SetAge(42).

Comment: Don't you get this problem with ordinary inheritance in languages such as C#? hence the base.something() call, or the Overriding of methods to hide the base?

Comment: Why would I implement a SetAge in Cat if I didn't want to override? I can still call the SetAge method within the Cat SetAge method?

Comment: With protected fields you can directly access them in methods of derived classes. Here you would have to create public accessor methods for those field, even if you don't want to make them public. I just took the SetAge() method as example. But think of any other method due to the logic. You don't hide the method of the parent type, it's callable as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned C#, try to do this in go. Method calls can't be made virtual in Go (except through interfaces).

```cs
// this is C#, not go
public class Thing 
{
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual int Age {get; set;}
}

public class Person : Thing {}
public class Cat : Thing 
{
    public override int Age 
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Age * 7; //age in cat's years
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Thing t = new Cat() {Name="Tom", Age=5}; // a Cat object is assigned 
                                         // to a Thing variable
Console.WriteLine(t.Age); // outputs 35. 
                          // t.Age refers to Cat's implementation 
                          // of Age, not Thing's. Notice how Age is virtual 
                          // in Thing and overridden in Cat
```

Comment: Check my code above...I added an override in Go...didn't do much to the override..but it does something.

Comment: the difference is not the override itself. It's in how you call it (and how the virtual call is resolved to the actual derived type that the variable contains). If I have time I'll try adding a counter-example in Go

Comment: You talking about shared memory space?

Comment: well yes, the constructor in Go is something else :)